Find the value of one angle out of four angles that all add up to a straight angle (180 degrees)
Find the value of angle $\angle \text{ABE}$ from problem #37 of the diagram and the information given:
$\angle \text{ABC}$ is a straight angle as per the diagram.
Ray $\overrightarrow{\text{BH}}$ bisects angle $\angle \text{EBC}$, angle $\angle \text{ABE} = 2n+7$ and adjacent angle $\angle \text{EBF} = 4n-13.$
I'm stumped in finding the value of angle $\angle \text{ABE}$. What am I missing?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please include a diagram/picture of this.

Where are these problems from? Problem 37 is under constrained, as @Sum says, it could take a range of values as n.

Do we have any conditions like n must be an integer? What i would suggest is using inequalities on the angles and finding the range of n

Let's name the angle ABE $\theta_1$, angle EBF $\theta_2$, angle FBH $\theta_3$ and angle HBC $\theta_4$

$\theta_1 = 2n+7$ (given)
$\theta_2 = 4n - 13$ (given)
$\theta_2 + \theta_3 = \theta_4$ (deduced from $\overrightarrow{BH}$ bisects EBC)
$\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 + \theta_4 = 180$ (angles on a straight line)

now let's construct the Augmented matrix of those equations
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2n+7 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4n-13 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & -1& 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 &  1& 180
 \end{array}\right]$$
$$r_4 - r_3 \rightarrow r_4 $$
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2n+7 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4n-13 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & -1& 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 &  2& 180
 \end{array}\right]$$
$$r_4 - r_1 \rightarrow r_4 \\ r_3 - r_2 \rightarrow r_3$$
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2n+7 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4n-13 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -1& -4n+13 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 &  2& -2n+173
 \end{array}\right]$$
$$r_3 + \tfrac{1}{2}r_4 \rightarrow r_3 \\ \tfrac{1}{2}r_4 \rightarrow r_4 $$
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2n+7 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4n-13 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0& -5n+99.5 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 &  1& -n+86.5
 \end{array}\right]$$

$\theta_1 = 2n+7$
$\theta_2 = 4n-13$
$\theta_3 = -5n+99.5$
$\theta_4 = -n + 86.5$

now we need to determine the range for n that make all thetas to be positive integer
$$2n+7 \ge  0 \rightarrow n \ge -3.5$$
$$4n-13 \ge 0 \rightarrow n \ge  3.25$$
$$-5n+99.5 \ge 0 \rightarrow n \le 19.9$$
$$-n+86.5 \ge 0 \rightarrow n \le 86.5$$
then the range for n should be between 3.25 and 19.9 then the angle ABE ($\theta_1$) should be between 23.25+7 = 13.5 and 219.9+7 = 46.8
Answer is ABE can be any value in closed interval $[13.5,46.8]$ to avoid zero angle in $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ make it open interval $(13.5,46.8)$.

This is incorrect, look at my answer below. The question needs only simple algebra, and it would be outrageous to assume a middle schooler could think of such a solution

Notice the small red arc drawn on $\angle \text{ABE}$ and $\angle \text{FBE}$. This signifies they are equal angles. Thus, $$2n+7 = 4n-13$$ $$\implies n=10$$
$$ \implies \angle \text{ABE} = 27°$$
The textbook should have made this more explicit, but this is a well known notation to signify equal angles, so it would benefit you to remember it.

I'm sorry, but this is not correct: equal angles (or line segments) are depicted by a small bar, crossing that angle or that segment. This gives the opportunity to make "couples" of equal angles or segments, using one single bar for the first couple, two bars of the second couple, ...

Hello, I am not sure about which country you are from, but in my country, all middle school textbooks use arcs to denote equal angles, and small bars to denote equal segments. It also seemed the most sensible option to me, since any other method would give multiple answers

Whay he didn't mension that the Ray $\overrightarrow{\text{EB}}$ bisects angle $\angle \text{EBF}$ as he says Ray $\overrightarrow{\text{BH}}$ bisects angle $\angle \text{EBC}$ !! ... this notation for me is just sys that is an angle  as @Dominique says he need to add small crossing bar on it to say they are equal angles

How does $EB$ bisect $\angle\text{EBF}$, do you mean $\angle\text{ABF}$, because in that cause my above answer is still valid. Also why would one signify just two angles out of all of them for no reason

There is no single definitive solution to it. If you try to substitute two different values for $m \angle \text{ABE}$ such as $n=10$ or $n=12$, you will find they both fit the question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I tried n= 20, as suggested, which resulted in angle FBH = - 1/2.  That, of course, is not acceptable.

I'm so sorry,I read the numbers wrong. You can try smaller values, like n=10 or 12.

Abbas is correct.

As said in the comment, you won't find a single value, but a range of values.
First, $\angle \mathit{EBF}$ needs to be positive, then
$$\begin{align}4n-13 &>0\\n>\frac{13}{4}\end{align}$$
Second, $\angle \mathit{EBF}$ needs to be inside $\angle \mathit{EBH}$, which is half the value $180° - \angle \mathit{ABE}$.
$$\begin{align}
2\angle \mathit{EBF} &< 180°-\angle \mathit{ABE}\\
2(4n-13)&< 180-(2n+7)\\
n&<\frac{199}{10}
\end{align}$$
These two inegalities mean $3.25 < n < 19.9$.
Finally
$$\begin{align}
2*3.25+7 &< \angle \mathit{ABE} < 2*19.9+7\\
13.5 &< \angle \mathit{ABE} < 46.8
\end{align}$$
If $n$ needs to be an integer, we adjust the values of $n$
$$\begin{align}
4&\leq n\leq 19\\
2*4+7 &\leq \angle \mathit{ABE} \leq 2*19+7\\
15 &\leq \angle \mathit{ABE} \leq 45
\end{align}$$
